# How to iterate HashMap database items onto ComboBox

Tags: javafx

I have created a HashMap from my database. Now I wish to display the HashMap to the ComboBox named cmbCourses. The problem with my code is that it is read as a String rather than a ObservableList, how do I iterate the values to match an ObservableList?

Here is my code:

```
public void populateCourse() {
    QueryCombo qc = new QueryCombo();
    HashMap<String, Integer> map = qc.hashMap();

    for (String s : map.keySet()) {
        cmbCourse.setItems(s);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a `ObservableList<String>` on your own

```
ObservableList<String> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList(items.keySet());
cmbCourse.setItems(items);
```

or simply fill the existing items list of the `ComboBox`

```
cmbCourse.getItems().setAll(map.keySet());
```

---

*I assume you want the list to contain the keys btw.*

Comment: This works. Now all I have to do is get the primary keys to insert into the database. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop only get **Hashmap** keys only, I think you want a key mapped object to set your `cmbCourse`,

you can do it like this,

```
for (String s : map.keySet()) {
        cmbCourse.addItem(map.get(s));
    }
```

but this is not the iteration.

**This is how to do a correct iteration**

```
HashMap<String, Integer> map = qc.hashMap();
Iterator it = map.entrySet().iterator();

while (it.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
    System.out.println(pair.getKey()); // this is your key
    System.out.println(pair.getValue()); //  // this is your key mapped value 
    it.remove(); // avoids a ConcurrentModificationException
}
```

Comment: How do I add this to the ComboBox? Is cmbCourse.setItems(it) enough?

Comment: I added the Object using `setItems` but it gives me an error.

Comment: Should the iteration be included in my code? I am a little bit confused sorry.

Comment: No, your code doesn't include iteration, what you're doing in your code, you have a Hashmap and hashmap include key & value pairs,  so what you doing in your code, you get the all keys in hashmap, `map.keySet()`  do that job.  Then loop those keys and get each object in hashmap according to key. `map.get(key)` do that job.